# Can't find module 'filepath' in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, module, mocha.js

This is my folder structure.

/node_modules/

```
   ....
   ....
```

/src/

```
   ....
   index.ts
        export default app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 3000')
    });
   ....
```

tsconfig.json

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "@types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include" : [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

/test/

```
   hello.ts
```

```
      const chaai = require('chai')
      const httpChai = require('chai-http')
      const server = require('../src/index')

      chaai.use(httpChai)

      describe('registration API', ()=>{
      describe('GET /api/register', ()=>{
       it("It should throw error", (done)=>{
           chaai.request(server)
           .post('/api/register')
        //    @ts-ignore
           .end((err, response)=>{
               response.status.should.equal(400)
               done()
           })
       })
   }) 
})
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha 'test/**/*.ts'"
  },
```

application structure

```
root
   node_modules
   src
      modules
         module1
         module2
      index.ts
   tsconfig.json
   package.json
```

Now when I run npm test, it says `Error: Cannot find module '../src/index'`
I tried moving test folder inside src folder also. But it didn't work. 
In test file, inside `/test/hello.ts` If I use import, says can't use import statement outside module.
And right now inside test file `/test/hello.ts`, I have required chai as `const chaai = require('chai')` and stored it in a `chaai` variable. But if I store it in a `chai` variable as `const chai = require('chai')`, then typescript warns `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'chai'.ts(2451) index.d.ts(1968, 15): 'chai' was also declared here.`
How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Could you share the file structure of your application, too?

Comment: I've updated application structure. Is that, what you meant?